# Implementation of selection sort algorithm is not working

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

I'm trying to improve my knowledge of a sort algorithm using Swift.

The swap function works fine on its own but when I want to use it in the selectionSort function it doesn't do what I expect it to do. `myArray` is  not sorted.

Here is my code:

```
func swap(var myArray:[Int], firstIndex: Int, secondIndex: Int) -> [Int] {
  let temp =  myArray[firstIndex]
  myArray[firstIndex] = myArray[secondIndex]
  myArray[secondIndex] = temp

  return myArray
}


func indexOfMinimum( myArray:[Int], startIndex: Int ) -> Int {
  // Set initial values for minValue and minIndex,
  // based on the leftmost entry in the subarray:

  var minValue = myArray[startIndex]
  var minIndex = startIndex

  // Loop over items starting with startIndex,
  // updating minValue and minIndex as needed:

 for(var i = minIndex + 1; i < myArray.count; i++){
    if( myArray[i] < minValue   ) {
      minIndex = i
      minValue =  myArray[i]
    }
  }
  return minIndex
}

// This function is not working properly

func selectionSort(myArray: [Int]) {
  var x: Int
  for ( var i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++) {
    x = indexOfMinimum( myArray,startIndex: i)
    swap(myArray, firstIndex: i, secondIndex: x)
  }
}

var myArray2 = [22, 11, 99, 88, 9, 7, 42]
selectionSort(myArray2)

myArray2 // that is the result that I'm getting [22, 11, 99, 88, 9, 7, 42] 

//while I should get [7, 9, 11, 22, 42, 88, 99]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what "doesn't work"?

Comment: The 3rd function called `selectionSort` is not working. It's doing nothing to the array. I tried to make it a return function that gives back an array of Integers but it didn't work

Comment: Swift arrays are *value types* which means that your original array is never modified. Read about inout parameters ...

Answer (score 2):

You can´t modify your original `Array`. Read more about value and reference types [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10). If you want to sort an array ASC you can just use `myArray2.sort({ $0 < $1 })`.

So to get your desired result just do.

```
myArray2 = myArray2.sort({ $0 < $1 })
print(myArray2)
```

And the result will be

```
[7, 9, 11, 22, 42, 88, 99]
```

Sort is a built in functionality in Swift.

**Update**

What you´re trying to do is called [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). One thing that you´re lacking is the comparison between two numbers. Another thing is the value types. If you want to find out exactly what you´re code is missing then you need to debug row for row, which is a good way to understand how your code is working and why it´s not behaving the way you want to.

Otherwise, here is a working Bubble sort function, that I can recommend you to learn how it works and use it instead.

```
func bubbleSort(inout numbers: [Int]) -> () {
    let numbersLength = numbers.count

    for var i = 0; i < numbersLength; i++ {
        for var j = 1; j < numbersLength-i; j++ {
            if numbers[j-1] > numbers[j] {
                let swap = numbers[j-1]
                numbers[j-1] = numbers[j]
                numbers[j] = swap
            }
        }
    }
}

func start(){
    // Numbers to sort
    var myArray = [22, 11, 99, 88, 9, 7, 42]

    // Print initial
    print("Initial:")
    for num in myArray {
        print("\(num) ")
    }

    // Execute Bubble Sort
    bubbleSort(&myArray)

    // Print result
    print("\nResult:")
    for num in myArray {
        print("\(num) ")
    }

    print(myArray)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I wanted to implement it from scratch to deepen my knowledge of the language.

Comment: Check the update, a bit more information for you @AziCode

Answer (score 2):

Your function is taking a parameter. You modify the parameter *in the function* and you don't return it at the end, so your function is essentially dead.

I don't know much about compiler optimization, but if I were a compiler I would just delete the `selectionSort(myArray2)` call because it literally does *nothing*. Your `swap` function returns a value but when you call it in `selectionSort` you don't use the return value. Xcode should give you an error for this.

At the end of the function, nothing has been modified because all variables that were modified are allocated in functions and go out of scope when they end.

What you are probably trying to do in `selectionSort` is:

```
myArray = swap(...);
```

What you are probably trying to do in the main part is

```
myArray = selectionSort(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting tripped up over why you can't alter a copied value type from within a function.

As [Arc676 suggests in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34478463/4151918), you could consider using the modified array you return, but you should keep in mind that mutating an array which you're also iterating through can be problematic.

Since your issue is purely for the purpose of understanding an algorithm, you should consider [the approach that Martin mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478394/why-is-my-implementation-of-the-selection-sort-algorithm-is-not-working#comment56698455_34478394), and use inout to alter the Array value type you're passing to the selectionSort and swap functions.

```
func swap(inout myArray:[Int], firstIndex: Int, secondIndex: Int) {
    let temp =  myArray[firstIndex]
    myArray[firstIndex] = myArray[secondIndex]
    myArray[secondIndex] = temp
}

func indexOfMinimum( myArray:[Int], startIndex: Int ) -> Int {
    // Set initial values for minValue and minIndex,
    // based on the leftmost entry in the subarray:

    var minValue = myArray[startIndex]
    var minIndex = startIndex

    // Loop over items starting with startIndex,
    // updating minValue and minIndex as needed:

    for(var i = minIndex + 1; i < myArray.count; i++){
        if( myArray[i] < minValue   ) {
            minIndex = i
            minValue =  myArray[i]
        }
    }
    return minIndex
}

func selectionSort(inout myArray: [Int]) {
    var x: Int
    for ( var i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++) {
        x = indexOfMinimum( myArray,startIndex: i)
        swap(&myArray, firstIndex: i, secondIndex: x)
    }
}

var myArray2 = [22, 11, 99, 88, 9, 7, 42]
selectionSort(&myArray2)

myArray2 //  Now you get[7, 9, 11, 22, 42, 88, 99]
```